# ZPL code sent to printer prints 2 blank labels before printing the actual label

Tags: zpl, zpl-ii

The following ZPL code when sent to a Zebra GX-420D printer with 2"x2" labeld loaded, does 2 very strange things:

- Skips the first 2 labels and only prints on the 3rd one
- Repeat this (2 blank labels + one with content) one more time, after a short delay.

So in total it uses 6 labels, and the content is only on the 3rd and 6th one.

Here's the code:

```
^XA
^FX Test for long barcode
^BY1,2,50
^FO20,10^BC^FD>6UIQ-2013P-MR-BU^FS
^XZ
```

Is there anything in the above code that would cause this phenomenon?

Comment: The only thing I see obviously wrong with the ZPL is the missing `^FS` after the comment text.

Comment: Thanks, @MarkWarren! I'll fix that and run a test again.

Comment: Does this printer have a calibration mode after power on or printer head closed? I know this behavior from printers like Z4M or ZM400, when they are not properly calibrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually figured it out. I was trying to remotely fix this, not having a direct access to the printer and not seeing what it printed and how. But eventually I got access to a printer and then it didn't take long to fix.

It seems that there were some defaults or setting left over from the previous print jobs that cause the problem. I added some resetting of values in front of the printing and after that it properly printed out just one label.

And yes, the ^FS was not needed at the end of the comment with ^FX.

Here is the code that printed out the same thing correctly (there might be some unnecessary commands but this one worked so I left it at that):

```
^XA~TA000~JSN^MNW^PON^PMN^LH0,000~SD15^XZ

^XA^JUS^XZ

^XA

^MMT
^PW0355
^LL0305

^FX Test for long barcode
^BY1,2,50
^FO20,10^BC^FD>6UIQ-2013P-MR-BU^FS
^XZ
```

Answer (score 1):

`^FS` at the end of a commented text is optional.

From ZPL II manual :

> The `^FS` command denotes the end of the field definition.
>   Alternatively, `^FS` command can also be issued as a single ASCII control code SI (`Control-O`, hexadecimal `0F`).